# Get formatted HTML from GeoJSON

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson

When I use Openlayers 3 I get data from PostGIS database and form it to GeoJSON and pass it on a vector layer.

So then I can do `event.selected[0].get('description')` to get the text that describes the selected feature and put it in a `div`.

I want to ask, if I save formatted HTML in the database like `<b>Title</b><br>blah blah <br><li>.....</li>` and use it to make GeoJSON, when I put it to a `div` will it appear as formatted or as text with the tags?

Will appear like

**Title**

blah blah

- List 1
- List 2

or like

`<b>Title</b><br>blah blah <br><ul><li>List 1</li><li>List 2</li></ul>` ?

Thanks

Comment: Why won't you try and see what happens? (it's not even an OpenLayers question so you could verify that in a single line of JS code in your browser's console)

Answer (score 1):

If you `div.innerHTML = event.selected[0].get('description');` then `description` will be rendered as HTML.